# Android reload grid view custom adapter

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

While I have a working 'solution' I really don't like it and think it will lead to memory issues. Ultimately I have an activity that comprises of a GridView which is populated by a Object Array - subjectsArrayList

On the activity I have a button where I want to 'reload' the array and update the grid view.

At present I have this:

```
// reload all subjects
        subjectAreas = "all";
        subjectsArrayList = populateSubjects();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), subjectsArrayList);
        gridView.invalidateViews();
        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I'm certain there is a more elegant method. My concern is that I'm creating another adapter instead of recycling it.

I've looked at notifyDataSetChanged() but not completely clear on how to use this, and my various attempts lead to nothing happening.

Questions: 
1) Is what I'm doing ok or am I correct in worrying abut re-creating my adapter each time?
2) Is there a better method to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- update the adapter with the new data
- call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the `GridView`

Better, you should use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) instead of a `GridView`

Comment: I suspected as much, however I can't seem to work out how to actually follow your steps. Keeping with GridView could you be so kind to provide code example?